# What is the maximum size of entries I can have in dnsmasq.conf

Tags: dnsmasq

What is the maximum size of entries, e.g. `server=/allow.com/#` and `address=/block.com/#` can I have in my dnsguardian config file `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`?

I already have hundreds inside. I would like to expand it to around a million. Would this impact its performance? Right now it is already reading all of them from `/etc/hosts` without considerable impact. But I would like to add them inside the `dnsmasq.conf` file. Would this make any difference?

Comment: `would like to expand it to around a million.` 10,000 you say?

Comment: No, 1,000,000 rules.

Comment: The fact that you're asking is probably because your gut feeling is the same as mine, a flat text configuration file can't be extended indefinitely without a noticeable performance impact or horrible failure. But such "what if" questions are often easily answered by simply testing and observing what happens.

Comment: Indeed. I was only seeking some rules already declared which I ignored. I shall try to test it soon.